# Place JavaScript in external file. File doesn't works?

Tags: .net, javascript

I have `GridView` with `CheckBox` in it's header and another one in each row:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this.checked)" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <input name="checkSelect" type="checkbox" value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want master checkbox to (un)check all others.

So I have `JavaScript` function:

```
function checkAll(checked) {
    var grid = document.getElementById("<%= gridViewStatement.ClientID %>");
    for (i = 1; grid.rows.length - 1; i++) {
        grid.rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked = checked;
    }
}
```

If I put it inside `<script>` tag, its works

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">       
</script>
```

If I put function in file

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
```

it stops working! File in in the root, names written correctly.

What am I doing wrong??

P.S. Is there anything I can improve my function?

P.P.S. I use `HtmlCheckBox` instead of `asp:CheckBox` because I bind each to column 'ID' and get list of IDs in `Request.Form`. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What kills your script, IMHO, is the line:

```
var grid = document.getElementById("<%= gridViewStatement.ClientID %>");
```

You are mixing server-side and client-side code. Since the server-side code is rendered first, if that line is present inside the ASPX page, then the value of `<%= gridViewStatement.ClientID %>` gets evaluated in time for it to be used by the JavaScript. By putting it in a file that gets included later, you're ensuring that the value does not get interpreted.

Here's a short solution:
At the top of your ASPX include the following lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var gridID = "<%= gridViewStatement.ClientID %>";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
```

And change the first line in your function to:

```
var grid = document.getElementById(gridID);
```

Comment: +1. I like this better than passing the `ClientID` as a parameter in `<input onclick>` because it keeps all the JavaScript together. The only problem with this is that it pollutes the global namespace. I can see a few solutions to that, such as `var serverValues = { 'gridViewStatement.ClientID': "<%= gridViewStatement.ClientID %>", 'nextServer.Key': "<%= another.Value %>" };` then `var grid = document.getElementById(serverValues['gridViewStatement.ClientID']);`

Comment: One other benefit to a `serverValues` map is that the client-side code can now more accurately reflect where the server value came from. Of course, a downside is that you have tied your client-side map key to a server-side variable name, but the original code had that dependancy as well.

Comment: Nice idea. I think I'll start using it from now on, rather than having a list of variables in the global scope. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your script contains a reference gridViewStatement.ClientID which is being evaluated on the asp.net page as an inline script. If you put it in an external file, this won't get evaluated and that script text will be in the javascript file on the client,which is not going to work because it doesn't have the proper id

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to LorenVS!!

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll('<%= gridViewStatement.ClientID %>', this.checked)" />
```

and

```
function checkAll(grid, checked) {
    var grid = document.getElementById(grid);
    for (i = 1; grid.rows.length - 1; i++) {
        var row = grid.rows[i];
        row.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked = checked;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As LorenVS said. Probably you can change your ASPX so that the client id of the grid is passed to the javascript function:

```
<input type="checkbox"
  onclick='checkAll(this.checked, "<%= gridViewStatement.ClientID %>")' />
```

Then change your function to take the grid's client ID as a parameter:

```
function checkAll(checked, gridId) {
  var grid = document.getElementById(gridId);
  ...
}
```

}